# Pop and push the same view does not invoke the viewWillAppear() method

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When I receive a local notification i do the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController pushViewController:notificationSplashViewController animated:YES];
}
```

If my `notificationSplashViewController` is the current ViewController, its `viewWillAppear()` method is not invoked. How can I detect the re-push of `notificationSplashViewController`?

Comment: wild guess - what happens if you animate the pop?

Comment: ... a disaster! The navigation bar gets crazy, overlapping all the titles of the pushed viewcontrollers. Actually, on the console I get:
`nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar`
`Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.`

Comment: Gaak! That is bad.  Don't do that :-)  Another wild guess - move the push into it's own method (called thePushMethod), and after the pop, invoke that method like this:   
[self performSelector:@selector(thePushMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

Comment: Fine! It works! :) Thank you!
Could you explain me why this workaround works?

Comment: When you invoke a selector like that, it does not do it in real time, it puts it on queue to be performed during the next run-loop, and that gives it enough time for the first animation to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[notificationSplashViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController pushViewController:notificationSplashViewController animated:YES];
```

for me, this did the trick.